# Python 3: Parse nested secondary arguments for initial set of choices

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Subcommands like `git commit` and `git status` can be easily parsed with `argparse` using `add_subparsers`. How does one get nested settings input for choices selected from command line?

Let's say I want to play music with all custom settings:

> > play.py --path /path/to.file --duration 100 --filter equalizer --effect echo equalizer_settings 1 2 echo_settings 5

Here `--filter equalizer` and `--effect echo` are first level choices but I need to get settings for those as secondary arguments. Ex: `echo_settings 5` and `equalizer_settings 1 2`.

Secondary settings could be more than one and preferably with named arguments.

Listed below is what I have so far...

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Play music the way I want it.')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--path', type=str, required=True, help='File path')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--duration', type=int, default=50, help='Play duration')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--filter', choices=['none', 'equalizer'], default='none', help='Filter selection')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--effect', choices=['none', 'echo', 'surround'], default='none', help='Effect selection')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='Settings of optional parameters')

equalizer_parser = subparsers.add_parser("equalizer_settings")
equalizer_parser.add_argument('equalizer_min_range', type=int)
equalizer_parser.add_argument('equalizer_max_range', type=int)

echo_parser = subparsers.add_parser("echo_settings")
echo_parser.add_argument('echo_strength', type=int)

surround_parser = subparsers.add_parser("surround_settings")
surround_parser.add_argument('surround_strength', type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Currently this errors in `error: unrecognized arguments`

Answer (score 0):

You can only use one subparser at a time, i.e. one of those 3 `settings`.  There are some advanced ways of using several subparsers in sequence, but I don't think we want to go there (see previous SO `argparse` questions).

But do you really need to use subparsers?  Why not just another set of optionals (flagged) arguments, something like:

```
parser.add_argument("--equalizer_settings", nargs=2, type=int)

parser.add_argument("--echo_settings", type=int)

parser.add_argument("--surround_strength", type=int
```

You are just adding some parameters, not invoking some sort of action command.

Comment: I did think of this, but was wondering if there is a better way to organize this.
Is it possible to make arguments as required based on condition of choice from earlier argument? Then probably I can work around with these.

Comment: The easiest way to make things conditionally required is to check for co-occurrence after parsing.  As it is `parse_args` does all the `required` checks as the last step.  Subparsers is the only builtin tool for conditionally required arguments.